# Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK (cordova + ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When running ionic build android

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

I tried updating sdk using 
    android update sdk -u

Comment: try to upgrade your sdk manually via SDK manager and convince that path in ANDROID_HOME is set properly

Comment: Updated sdk via SDK manager and set ANDROID_Home
    export ANDROID_HOME=/Library/Android/sdk
    export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

Comment: I ran into the same issue when updating from Android Studio 2.1 to 2.3, have you found a fix for this yet?

Answer (score 6):

update android project to cordova-android 6.2.1

```
ionic platform update android@6.2.1
```

for more details check the following links https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html

Answer (score 2):

Update manually `Android studio` using `SDK Manager`

[image]

please refer this link.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo-ur-android-sdk/22056

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for existing ionic project:

```
npm install -g cordova
cd <project_dir>
cordova platform update android
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install Gradle with PATH declaration working for me.